# Check if a layer has weights for a keras CNN

Tags: python, keras

I have a CNN which is made in keras.

I can view the weights of a specific layer using:

```py
weights,biases = model.layers[n].get_weights()
print(weights,biases)
```

But I want to view the weights in all relevant layers so I tried:

```py
for layer in model.layers:
    weights,biases = layer.get_weights()
```

But this throws an error for layers which don't have weights (like the `max pool` layer).

So is it possible to check if a layer has weights, something like:

```py
if layer.weights != None:
```

Edit: Added the keras model I am using

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(1, kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu', input_shape=(6,6,1)))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(len(sign_label_list),activation='relu'))
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for your model ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cold try this:

```py
for layer in model.layers: 
    if len(layer.get_weights()) > 0: 
        print(layer.name, layer.get_weights())
```

Comment: Thank you. The suggested way works but when printing using `layer.get_weights()`, it also displays some extra things.
I used `print(layer.get_weights()[0]) ` to display only the weights.